# How can I play blu-rays on an external monitor connected through a VGA output? (worried about HDCP)

Tags: vga, blu-ray, hdcp

Sorry if this is an obvious question, I can't find the answer.

My laptop only has the older VGA out (no HDMI or DVI). I'm considering getting a bluray drive for it, but I've heard HDCP might cause problems.

How do I watch blu-rays on an external monitor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially you don't. Thank big movie studios for that!

When you connect an analog receiver or a digital one without HDCP, there is a resolution limit in place. I can't get exact numbers right now, but it should still be better than regular DVD.

There are ways to circumvent the issue, but the fact that you don't have HDCP enable output makes it more problematic.

For HDP enabled sources there are devices such as [HDFury](http://www.hdfury.com/) for example which will strip out HDCP out o the video stream and enable analog connections, but that won't work for you since you don't have digital output.

So what you need is to remove the "protection" before it gets to video output. There are several ways to do that.

There are programs like for example [AnyDVD HD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvdhd.html) which are capable of removing  the protection.

Another way is to remove the protection yourself using various open-source utilities. For example [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) has some support for Blu-Ray disks and there is a [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD) for it too.

The problem with these two ways is that you need to copy data from BD-ROM to HDD and that will of course take up HDD space and need time.

I don't know of any way to decrypt and play disks on the fly with hardware which has no official support.

Answer (score 1):

I watch bluray movies on my HP Elitebook with VGA output to my monitor (1920 X 1280) using VLC with the bluray files available online that enable the open source program to play bluray movies. When I attempt to do so with the Cyberlink PowerDVD application, it refuses to play saying that my graphics card is not capable. The Cyberlink Bluray advisor says it's because of the analog (VGA) connection.